# Why did the Intel bubble memory chips have a hexadecimal label on them?

Tags: memory, intel

Such as in this image: [image: Intel Bubble Memory chip (from Wikipedia)]
I guess some sort of configuration, am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the hexadecimal digits indicate which minor loops should not be used, as per [Vintage Bubble Memory](https://web.archive.org/web/20190228095444/http://www.wylie.org.uk/technology/computer/bubblmem/bubblmem.htm).

Comment: Given the number of bits high in the label here and grid that exactly fills the label, one might wonder if they are a bitmap loops that *should be* used.  The label at your link has far few 1's so maybe those do indicate the bad loops.

Comment: Looking at the images on that page, there appear to have been several different notations used. If I had to guess, Intel (among others) used 1s for good loops, Motorola and Fujitsu (among others) used 1s for bad loops, and TI used some other sort of notation entirely.